# AngularJS: I can't understand a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can someone help me to understand this code? I've found this code in a project and I need a directive that allows only numeric input in text areas, can this help me?

```
controllerManager.directive('chars', function () { 

'use strict'; 
return { 
    require: 'ngModel', 
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs, ctrl) { 

        var regReplace, 
            preset = { 
                'specialChars': "^\x20-\x22\x27-\x3F\x41-\x59\x61-\x7B\x7D",
                'integer': "0-9"                    
            }, 
            filter = preset[attrs.chars] || attrs.chars; 

        $elem.on('input', function () { 
            regReplace = new RegExp('[' + filter + ']', 'ig'); 
            ctrl.$setViewValue($elem.val().replace(regReplace, '')); 
            ctrl.$render(); 

            var max = $elem.attr('maxLength');
            var len = $elem.val().length;
            document.getElementById($elem.attr('id')+"Count").innerHTML = max - len;
        }); 

    } 
}; 


});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/. And come back more specific questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below directive. It will only allow integer values to be entered and will discard any other character.

```
app.directive('integerOnly', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var oldValue = null;

            element.addClass('text-right');

            element.bind('focus', function () {
                return scope.$apply(function () {
                    return oldValue = element.val();
                });
            });

            return ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                var val = inputValue ? inputValue.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') : "";
                while (val < "1" && val != val.replace(/[^1-9]/, '')) {
                    val = val.replace(/[^1-9]/, '');
                }
                if (val !== inputValue) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(val);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return val;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with this change:

```
controllerManager.directive('chars', function () { 

'use strict'; 
return { 
    require: 'ngModel', 
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs, ctrl) { 

        var regReplace, 
            preset = { 
                'specialChars': "^\x20-\x22\x27-\x3F\x41-\x59\x61-\x7B\x7D",
                'integer': "^0-9"
            }, 
            filter = preset[attrs.chars] || attrs.chars; 

        $elem.on('input', function () { 
            regReplace = new RegExp('[' + filter + ']', 'ig'); 
            ctrl.$setViewValue($elem.val().replace(regReplace, '')); 
            ctrl.$render(); 

            var max = $elem.attr('maxLength');
            var len = $elem.val().length;
            document.getElementById($elem.attr('id')+"Count").innerHTML = max - len;
        }); 
    } 
}; 
});
```

So now this work:

```
<input type="text" chars="integer"/>
```